is there a closed form of the CF (characteristic function) of a bivariate von Mises distribution?
is there a closed form of the CF (characteristic function) of a  bivariate von Mises distribution?
And if I have two parameters that follow von Mises distribution, but my two parameters will be mixed so should I move to the bivariate von Mises, or can I stay and do my calculations with just the von Mises?
ps: sorry if it is not clear, it is my first time working with it!

Could you please (a) explain whether by "parameter" you really mean random variable and (b) tell us what you mean by "mixed"?
